# Mean function from rts package, returns empty dataset, R

Tags: raster, r, time-series

I am using the `rts` package in R and specifically the `mean` function, over a a gridded climatic dataset with many NA values. 
When I use `apply.yearly(my_rts_object,mean)` all I get is an empty raster time series.

Does anyone knows if a large number of NAs can introduce such a problem to the `rts` mean function? 
I did not find any infos regarding NAs in `rts` documentation and I would really like to know if anyone has faced a similar issue (other functions like min and max work fine and return values).

Comment: I think you look for something equivalent to na.rm=T for the rts package but probably someone else will be able to advise you where to look in order to solve this.

Comment: That is what I thought but it doesn't work. Weird thing though, when I tested the mean function over the same datasest (e.g. mean(my_stack,na.rm=T) it works.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your time and effort @samcarter. I will try this.